# How to uninstall a flatpak application "Open Drive"

Tags: uninstall, flatpak

I installed a Flatpak after figuring out that the equivalent Snap did not properly work on my device. Now I do not manage to uninstall the application via the remove button.
The app is OpenDrive, the error notification says: 
"Unable to remove Open Drive (Google Drive Client) io.github.liberodark.OpenDrive/x86/stable not installed" [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO6YG.png)

I do not understand this error message and I don't know how to finally get the app uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

list all flatpak application installed on your system using command:

```
flatpak list
```

then grab the app id of opendrive and run command to uninstall

```
flatpak uninstall <app-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing on what [@sarru1291](https://askubuntu.com/users/1048461/sarru1291) mentioned in his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1244160/75166).

You can use `flatpak uninstall --all` to simply uninstall **all** installed flatpaks.

Or use `flatpak uninstall --help` to get more options.